# Djcelery not working with xhtml2pdf - Mingle: all alone

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf, djcelery

Im trying to import xhtml2pdf in to my tasks.py file. But when ever I import it, no tasks gets done, as soons as I remove the import line, it works again. There is not error, its just does nothing.

taks.py:

```
from celery import task

import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa

@task
def some_task():
    return "HELLO"
```

> python manage.py celeryd -E -B -l DEBUG

just stays like this:

```
  . recurring_invoice.tasks.send_email
  . recurring_invoice.tasks.send_invoice

[2015-06-10 20:54:14,549: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2015-06-10 20:54:14,555: INFO/Beat] Writing entries...
[2015-06-10 20:54:14,588: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2015-06-10 20:54:14,613: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-06-10 20:54:15,630: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone

/Users/hermanstander/apps/afriapps/stem/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:136: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2015-06-10 20:34:13,870: WARNING/MainProcess] /Users/hermanstander/apps/afriapps/stem/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/loaders.py:136: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2015-06-10 20:34:13,870: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Hermans-MacBook-Air.local ready.
[2015-06-10 20:34:13,870: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2015-06-10 20:34:13,871: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->16
```

Im  using Django 1.8, python 2.7

Comment: Well, for what its worth, I uninstalled xhtmlm2pdf and installed Weasyprint. Now everything works